# TypeError: Type contract Campaign is not implicitly convertible to expected type address

Tags: solidity, addresses

pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

```
contract CampaignFactory {
    address[] public deployedCampaigns;

    function createCampaign(uint minimum) public {
        address newCampaignAddress = new Campaign(minimum, msg.sender);
        deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaignAddress);
    }

    function getDeployedCampaing() public view returns(address[]memory) {
        return deployedCampaigns;
    }
}
contract Campaign {

    struct Request {
        string description;
        uint value;
        address payable recipient;
        bool complete;
        uint approvalCount;
        mapping(address => bool) approvals;
    }

    Request[] public requests;
    address public manager;
    uint public minimumContribution;
    mapping(address => bool) public approvers;
    uint public approversCount;

    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }

    constructor(uint minimum, address creator) public {
        manager = creator;
        minimumContribution = minimum;
    }

    function contribute() public payable {
        require(msg.value > minimumContribution);
        approvers[msg.sender] = true;
        approversCount++;
    }

    function createRequest(string memory description, uint value, address payable recipient) public restricted {
        Request memory newRequest = Request({
            description: description,
            value: value,
            recipient: recipient,
            complete: false,
            approvalCount: 0
        });

        requests.push(newRequest);
    }

    function approveRequest(uint index) public {
        Request storage request = requests[index];

        require(approvers[msg.sender]);
        require(!request.approvals[msg.sender]);

        request.approvals[msg.sender] == true;
        request.approvalCount++;
    }

    function finalizeRequest(uint index) public restricted{
        Request storage request = requests[index];

        require(request.approvalCount > (approversCount / 2));
        require(!request.complete);

        request.recipient.transfer(request.value);
        request.complete = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a error on line 7,

Comment: you didn't mention what the error message is, but I bet it's because you are assigning a `Campaign` object to an `address` variable.

Comment: right not thise error was solved , but ı have got new erros message when ı click minimum contribition output is like ; call to Campaign.minimumContribution errored: VM error: revert.
revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the issue is on this line:

```
address newCampaignAddress = new Campaign(minimum, msg.sender);
```

`newCampaignAddress` is an `address`, while the right hand side of the assignment is not. It's a `Campaign`. As the error message indicates, Solidity will not *implicitly* cast from `Campaign` to `address`. You can, however, *explicitly* cast the value:

```
address newCampaignAddress = address(new Campaign(minimum, msg.sender));
```